# Desktops combining in the afternoon, all programs on 1 desktop

Tags: workspace, desktop-environment

I've been purchasing elementary OS since 2017, and using Linux since 1996. I use 3 desktops, 1 is a personal browser/email on Chrome, workspace 2 is a work browser on Microsoft Edge (Chromium was having issues). 3rd desktop is a file folder and open PDF files for work. Around the same time every afternoon, both browsers and files move to the same desktop/workspace. If I open a new workspace, they all move to the new one, but they are "ghosts", meaning I have to return to the original desktop to interact with the browser. I'd like to blame Microsoft for this (kidding :) but has anyone experienced this, and found a way to stop it? Thanks!